# Changing color roles discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

First, I would like to point out that I am a beginner with python.

I am trying to write a command that allows the user to change the color of his role via the bot. However, I have encountered many problems that I can not find an answer to.

The first problem was that I could not get access to the role of the user calling the command. 
I decided, however, to skip it and go straight to a specific role.
So i made this code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=1)
async def changecolor(ctx, NewColor):
    author = ctx.message.author
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    dictOfColors = { '1' : discord.Color.default(),
                     '2' : discord.Color.teal(),
                     '3' : discord.Color.dark_teal(),
                     '4' : discord.Color.green(),
                     '5' : discord.Color.dark_green(),
                     '6' : discord.Color.blue(),
                     '7' : discord.Color.purple(),
                     '8' : discord.Color.dark_purple(),
                     '9' : discord.Color.magenta(),
                     '10' : discord.Color.dark_magenta(),
                     '11' : discord.Color.gold(),
                     '12' : discord.Color.dark_gold(),
                     '13' : discord.Color.orange(),
                     '14' : discord.Color.dark_orange(),
                     '15' : discord.Color.red(),
                     '16' : discord.Color.dark_red() }
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name='New Member')
    if NewColor in dictOfColors:
        await client.edit_role(server, role, colour=NewColor)
```

But when I try: `.changecolor 5` receives this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can you give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jaba https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line to

```
await client.edit_role(server, role, colour=dictOfColors[NewColor])
```

You're assigning the number of the color you want from your dictionary to the `colour` attribute instead of the value at that key which is the actual color.

Comment: @ArtFiNCH Hello, I've noticed you haven't accepted any answers to the questions you've been asking since you've joined SO. You should consider choosing an answer that helped you and accepting it so others can see the solution. Check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a role [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the role from a role mention.  I would also make it so the user passes the name of the color instead of a number:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def changecolor(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, color):
    if role not in ctx.message.author.roles:
        await bot.say("You do not have the role " + role.name)
        return
    color = '_'.join(color.lower().split())
    if not hasattr(discord.Color, color):  # We could also use inspect.ismethod to only accept classmethod names
        await bot.say("I do not recognize the color " + color)
        return
    await client.edit_role(ctx.message.server, role, colour=getattr(discord.Color, color)())
```

You would then call this with something along the lines of

```
!changecolor @NewMember dark gold
```

Comment: Thanks you also, it works well but i would like to make this code that user can switch his role color, but no others. Is there any option to this? Because right now i need to set exact role name right here `role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name='Role Name')`

I would like also stay with my code because i just don't like using code which i don't understand, for example ` color = '_'.join(color.lower().split()) ` i have no idea how is it working.

Comment: @ArtFiNCH Yeah, you can just check `role not in ctx.message.author.roles`.  This works because the role converter gives us a `Role` object instead of a string.

Comment: `'_'.join(list_of_strings)` joins the strings together using `_`.  So `'_'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` is `'a_b_c'`.  `phrase.lower().split()` converts a string to lowercase then splits it on the whitespace.  So `'A b C'` becomes `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  I'm doing this to take the color as a natural-looking string and converting it into the method name: `Dark Gold` -> `dark_gold` for example

Comment: Okay I tested it out, it works way better than my code, but still i need a little more explanations. I know already that line with .join is for converting. How I said, I'm really a beginner. `async def changecolor(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, color):` What do it means? `(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, color)` First one is a ctx okay, the second means that we are giving role from discord.Role(?), but what's 3th? Is it means like we can give more than one role?

Comment: @ArtFiNCH `role: discord.Role` is a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters).  By providing a type hint, we tell `discord.py` to intercept the string from the user and turn it into a `Role` object for us.  The `*, color` syntax is telling `discord.py` to consolidate all the input after it [into a single string](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).  So for input `!changecolor @SomeRole a b c` we get the `Role` object representing that role and the string `"a b c"`