# Changing user's role colour to select hex value in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
async def vanity(ctx, rolename=None, hexcolour=None):
    savepath = "--"
    userFile = os.path.join(savepath, str(ctx.author.id) + ".txt")
    server = client.get_guild(--)
    if os.path.exists(userFile):
        await ctx.send("No")
    if rolename == None:
        await ctx.send("Please include a name")
    elif hexcolour == None:
        await ctx.send("Please include a hexadecimal colour value")
    elif os.path.exists(userFile):
        vanityFile = open(userFile, "a+")
        vanityFile = vanityFile.read()
        await ctx.send(vanityFile)
        vanityrole = server.get_role(int(vanityFile))
        vanityrole = vanityrole.edit(name = str(rolename), colour = int("0x" + hexcolour, 16))
    else:
        vanityFile = open(userFile, "a+")
        vanityrole = await server.create_role(name = str(rolename), colour = int("0x" + hexcolour, 16))
        vanityFile = vanityFile.write(str(vanityrole.id))
        await client.add_roles(ctx.author, vanityrole)
```

This is my code (with some things omitted for privacy reasons), when I run it I get the error

```py
 vanityrole = await server.create_role(name = str(rolename), colour = int("0x" + hexcolour, 16))
  File "/home/--/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1589, in create_role
    fields['color'] = colour.value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

My code is for someone to edit/create their vanity role on the server. At the moment I'm struggling with how to get the colour the user inputs in the command and set the role to that colour using hexadecimal.

Comment: I did it by getting the name of the color from the user and calling the `Color` classmethod with that name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782098/changing-color-roles-discord/52782322#52782322

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```py
colour = int("0x" + hexcolour, 16)
```

This should work:

```
colour = discord.Colour(int(f"0x{hexcolour}, 16))
```

Although I'm answering 11 months after the question was asked. I'm answering here for anyone in the future that may come across this problem and needs help just like I was.

Hopefully this may be of help for anyone that comes across this problem.